# extract a specific revision of the git repository

Tags: git

My level in regards to git is `beginner`: I'm basically able to commit, pull, push and switch/create branches.

My current commit is `222222222` and a previous one in the same branch was `111111111`.

I want to retrieve the branch as it was on commit `111111111`, copy the files it contained and go back to `222222222` so I can continue my work based on that commit. Revert seems to be what I need.

Using revert, I can have the following (revert also commits if I understand properly):

1. commit `111111111`
2. commit `222222222`
3. revert to `111111111` (it also commits `111111111` again)
4. revert to `222222222` (it also commits `222222222` again)

But I don't want the reverts to appear in my history.

So how can I actually take a snapshot of my repository at the moment of my commit `111111111`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Git, *commits themselves* are repository snapshots. You just need to switch between them.

---

No, `git revert` is *not* what you need, because it's specifically made *to* make the reverts appear in history. The described actions are what `git checkout` does, instead.

To remain at `22222` but copy some or all files from an older commit:

```
git checkout 11111 file1.c file2.txt dir1
[or]
git checkout 11111 .
```

(as always, the `.` means "current directory")

To temporarily switch the entire repository to an old commit, then go back:

```
git checkout 11111
[copy files]
git checkout master
```

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I needed :)